# openldap, I can't add user, invalid DN

Tags: ldap, redhat, openldap

I start my test openldap server on RedHat enterprise linux 6.5. I configured it properly I think. I add my base.ldif file which looks like that:

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
dc: example
description: Root LDAP entry for example.com
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: rootObject

dn: ou=People,dc=exapmle,dc=com
ou: People
description: All people in organisation
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

Using command:

```
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" -f base.ldif
```

I got an output:

```
[root@melita-bladekp ~]# ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" -f base.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "dc=example,dc=com"

adding new entry "ou=People,dc=exapmle,dc=com"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

But i tried second time and I receive:

```
[root@melita-bladekp ~]# ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" -f base.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_add: Already exists (68)
```

So it looks okay for me, next I tried to add an user:

```
dn: uid=ldapuser100,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
uid: ldapuser100
cn: ldapuser100
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword: {crypt}$6$E/tH1oRF$9.Km8Xs/wDIFgWgTT.domcw0PJGUZqK7mqdFPaNru2il5LMgsxaowq5bvjulQLR8CqSq.Pw.brZU77fzviQPG.
shadowLastChange: 16460
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1400
gidNumber: 1400
homeDirectory: /exports/ldapuser100
```

Using command:

```
[root@melita-bladekp ~]# ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" -f ldapuser100.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "uid=ldapuser100,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_add: No such object (32)
        matched DN: dc=example,dc=com
```

And I receive that DN didn't exists. I think there is problem with that base file, do you have any idea what I can do to fix it?

My conf files(I think that the conf files are ok):

/etc/openldap/ldap.conf

```
  BASE dc=example,dc=com
    URI ldap://localhost
    TLS_REQCERT never
```

/etc/openldap/slapd.conf

```
 include         /etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/duaconf.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
    include         /etc/openldap/schema/collective.schema

    pidfile         /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
    argsfile        /var/run/openldap/slapd.args


    TLSCACertificatePath /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.crt
    TLSCertificateFile /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.crt
    TLSCertificateKeyFile /etc/openldap/certs/ldap.key

    database config
    access to *
            by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
            by * none

    database monitor
    access to *
            by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" read
            by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" read
            by * none

    database        bdb
    suffix          "dc=example,dc=com"
    checkpoint      1024 15
    rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"

    rootpw        {SSHA}MdddSPNLtlsVia4T534qLL6LWLRy2lBB
    directory       /var/lib/ldap

    index objectClass                       eq,pres
    index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
    index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
    index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
    index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
```

Comment: When you have executed your initial command for the second time, the already-exists message was related to "dc=example,dc=com" object and "ou=People,..." is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a typo in the `dn` of your LDIF

```
dn: ou=People,**dc=exapmle**,dc=com
```

If you change `exapmle` to `example` and re-run the LDIF with continue on error you should get the example entry and then you will be able to add your user afterwards.